# Bridge-To-Kubernetes doesn't work if the ClusterUser is AAD integrated and requires MFA

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I have an AAD integrated AKS private cluster. I'm able to connect to it from my PC using kubectl commands and run kubectl commands without any issues. However, when I connect via Bridge-To-Kubernetes extension in Visual Studio 2019. I keep getting error while trying to fetch Namespaces, it gives me an error "User: xxxx doesn't have appropriate auth credentials in the kubeconfig".

Also, How to change the Bridge-to-Kubernetes user to use clusteradmin user instead of AAD user by default?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how useful this may be for you, but I got this working using the --admin flag when using get credentials...

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group [resource group name] --name [cluster name] --admin
```

This merges admin credentials into your local .kubeconfig
In the Bridge to Kubernetes edit profile dialog, I get a new option for Context.
Select the one appended with -admin and it'll use the new admin credentials to fetch the namespaces.